# Grafana shows inconsistent behavior when changing time interval

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I have these two queries, fetching Loki logs

```
1: sum(count_over_time({container="pippo", namespace="family"} |= `fancy logs` [5m]))


2: sum(count_over_time({container="pippo", namespace="family"} |= `fancy logs` [1h]))
```

I run them on a 7 days interval (previous 7 days).

The first query returns 'No data', while the second returns some points.

Normally, I would expect the same occurrences, grouped differently: instead of having 12 points of amplitude 1 occurring every 5m , I would have a single point with amplitude 12 when grouping on 1h.

How would you explain this? Am I misunderstanding it or is there a bug/inconsistence?

Edit: my only explanation could be that with 5 minutes, the ~2000 horizontal `buckets` would be more than the number of pixels available in the plot. However in this case I consider 'No data' to be a totally misleading error message.

Comment: It seems like you have problems with resolution. I'm not that experienced with loki, but for Prometheus Grafana selects resolution and only asks Prometheus to provide result every once in set resolution. This is the reason your are advised to use `$__rate_interval` instead of fixed values like `5m`. This advise is only try for Prometheus, but I believe Loki has something like `$__auto`.

Comment: Here is official recommendation regarding `$__auto`: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/connect-externally-hosted/data-sources/loki/template-variables/#use-__auto-variable-for-loki-metric-queries

Comment: And FYI "No data" is not an error message: Grafana passed your query to Loki, it didn't return any data, hence "No data". No errors happen, and this is somewhat expected behaviour for some cases.

Comment: `$__interval` seems to be the correct solution. Thanks for the docs

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the correct way is to use `$__interval` instead of the time interval:

```
sum(count_over_time({container="pippo", namespace="family"} |= `fancy logs` [$__interval]))
```